# Como verificar se um caractere é letra ou número?

Tags: java, string

```
System.out.print("Frase: ");
    String frase = sc.nextLine(); // Exemplo: a1b2c3d4

for (int i = 0; i < frase.length; i++) {
    if (frase.chatAt(i)...........// Qual método ou lógica que verifique se esse char é LETRA ou NÚMERO?    
}
```

Alguém conhece o método ou a lógica que se encaixa no problema? Se souber outra forma de fazer essa verificação fique à vontade.

Answer (score 4):

A classe `Character` tem métodos para verificar se um caractere é letra, número, etc. Veja todas as opções na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html), mas uma solução para o seu caso seria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
    char c = frase.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        System.out.println(c + " é número");
    } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        System.out.println(c + " é letra");
    } else {
        System.out.println(c + " não é letra nem número");
    }
}
```

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/466486/112052) só usou `isDigit` e assumiu que se não é número, então é letra. Mas se a string tiver caracteres que não são letras nem números (como espaço, sinais de pontuação, *emojis*, etc), aí o código sugerido por ela não funciona mais, pois ele dirá erroneamente que todos esses caracteres são letras. E como não é citada esta restrição, temos que assumir que pode ser digitado qualquer coisa no texto.

---

Poderíamos parar por aqui, mas acho que vale a pena aprofundar mais um pouco. A definição de "letra" e "número" vai muito além do nosso alfabeto. Por exemplo, os caracteres abaixo são considerados dígitos:

```
// todas as linhas abaixo imprimem "true"
System.out.println(Character.isDigit('۸'));
System.out.println(Character.isDigit('۹'));
System.out.println(Character.isDigit('۵'));
```

Isso acontece porque [`isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) considera todos os dígitos definidos pelo Unicode que estão na categoria "Number, Decimal Digit" (são todos [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)).

O mesmo vale para letras, pois [`isLetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) considera todas as letras definidas pelo Unicode (são os caracteres que estão nas categorias que começam com "L" [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)). Ou seja, letras de outros alfabetos também são consideradas (por exemplo, `Character.isLetter('親')` retorna `true`).

Se a ideia é limitar a letras de `a` a `z` e dígitos de `0` a `9` (e sem considerar letras acentuadas e o `ç`), aí poderia ser feito assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
    char c = frase.charAt(i);
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
        System.out.println(c + " é número");
    } else if (('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')) {
        System.out.println(c + " é letra");
    } else {
        System.out.println(c + " não é letra nem número");
    }
}
```

Se for para considerar letras acentuadas, teria que ter mais uma condição no segundo `if`. Mas você também deveria levar em conta as formas de normalização, que não vou entrar em detalhes, mas há explicações bem mais detalhadas a respeito [aqui](/q/406545/112052), [aqui](/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](/a/345946/112052).

---

Por fim, se a ideia for verificar apenas se é letra ou número, **sem especificar qual desses dois você quer**, outra opção é usar [`isLetterOrDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
    char c = frase.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
        System.out.println(c + " é letra ou número");
    } else {
        System.out.println(c + " não é letra nem número");
    }
}
```

Lembrando que `isLetterOrDigit` usa os mesmos critérios de `isLetter` e `isDigit` (ou seja, leva em conta todos os caracteres definidos pelo Unicode). Se quiser fazer algo similar apenas para o nosso alfabeto (sem considerar acentos) e dígitos de `0` a `9`, ficaria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
    char c = frase.charAt(i);
    if (('0' <= c && c <= '9') || ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')) {
        System.out.println(c + " é letra ou número");
    } else {
        System.out.println(c + " não é letra nem número");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa Character.isDigit(...)

```
if(Character.isDigit(frase.charAt(i))){

}
```

Se for verdadeiro, é número, senão é letra